# Heroku - SQL query return difference results on localhost and heroku

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, intervals

I have in a table the date column `birthday` with, eg. the value `2003-05-01`.
On this table I run the following query:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (users.birthday < current_date - interval '15' year);
```

On my localhost, the row with `birthday: 2003-05-15` is not returned (that's correct), but on heroku it does.

Locally I use PostgreSQL database, so that's why I don't understand, how is possible to get on the same query two difference results...

Did anyone have similar problem? What could be the problem of this behavior?

Thank you for every advice.

Comment: What is the value of `current_date` according to Heroku?

Comment: Maybe `SELECT current_date` and see what the result is?

Comment: So, `select current_date;` on Heroku returns `2012-04-26` (on my local postgresql database as well).

Comment: How many rows are in the `users` table?  Are there other rows which are correctly not returned on Heroku?

Comment: in the table is around 5-6 rows. Yes, there are... but all not correctly returned rows are those, which are selected with the `current_date` rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the "year" inside the string with the value "15".  It's a long shot, but it may be that Heroku is silently removing the "year" thinking that it's a column alias:

```
db=# select current_date - interval '15' year;
      ?column?       
---------------------
 1997-04-26 00:00:00

db=# select current_date - interval '15'
        years        
---------------------
 2012-04-25 23:59:45

db=# select current_date - interval '15 year';
      ?column?       
---------------------
 1997-04-26 00:00:00
```